# Spring Security OpenID access login page hidden form input value using CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

According to the [API](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/openid/OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.html),
The OpenID authentication involves two stages:

Submission of OpenID identity

Processing the Redirect from the OpenID Server

My task is to capture the first stage and extract the extra information from the submission.

After some investigation, I have came out with the following:

The spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <security:http pattern="/myapp/auth/login" security="none"/>
    <security:http pattern="/myapp/auth/logout" security="none"/>
    <security:http entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/myapp/main/*" access="ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/myapp/auth/login"
            logout-url="/myapp/auth/logout"/>  
        <security:custom-filter position="OPENID_FILTER" ref="openIdAuthFilter"/>
    </security:http>

  <bean id="openIdAuthFilter" class="org.myorg.openid.filter.CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <property name="consumer">
      <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
          <bean class="org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager"/>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1">
          <list value-type="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="email"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://schema.openid.net/contact/email"/>
              <property name="required" value="true"/>
              <property name="count" value="1"/>           
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="firstName"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://axschema.org/namePerson/first" />
              <property name="required" value="true"/>
              <property name="count" value="1"/>     
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAttribute">
              <constructor-arg index="0" value="lastName"/>
              <constructor-arg index="1" value="http://axschema.org/namePerson/last" />
              <property name="required" value="true"/>
              <property name="count" value="1"/>     
            </bean>
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>  
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider ref="openIdAuthProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>
  <bean id="openIdAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService" ref="registeringUserService"/>
  </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/myapp/main/translationpage.jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
         <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/myapp/auth/login?error=true" />
    </bean>
<!--
    A custom UserDetailsService which will allow any user to authenticate and "register" their IDs in an internal map
    for use if they return to the site. This is the most common usage pattern for sites which use OpenID.
 -->
    <bean id="registeringUserService" class="org.myorg.openid.service.CustomUserDetailsService" />

  <bean id="entryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/myapp/auth/login"/>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter.java, which tries to extract the extra information from login.jsp

```
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) 
    throws IOException,ServletException{
        System.out.println("==before login==");
        String language = request.getParameter("language");
        System.out.println("language= " + language);
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
        System.out.println("==after login==");
    }
```

The login.jsp
prints "language= null".
I am very new to spring mvc and security, did i miss anything? Thanks.
OK, finally I think I got it.

At http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#doFilter%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse,%20javax.servlet.FilterChain%29, it states that "Return null, indicating that the authentication process is still in progress. Before returning, the implementation should perform any additional work required to complete the process.". But I was trying to print it out.

The final CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter is

```
public class CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter extends OpenIDAuthenticationFilter{

public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws AuthenticationException, IOException {
    System.out.println("==attemptAuthentication==");
    String language = request.getParameter("language");
    System.out.println("language= " + language);
    Authentication au = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
    //System.out.println(au.getPrincipal());
    return au;
}
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) 
throws IOException,ServletException{
    System.out.println("==before login==");
    super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
    System.out.println("==after login==");
}

protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed)
throws IOException,ServletException{
    System.out.println("==before failed login==");
    super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
    System.out.println("==after failed login==");
}
```

}

Comment: I have tried ModelMap, but still out of luck.

Comment: After adding in public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) in CustomOpenIDAuthenticationFilter, I can print language= hello world,but I got a Null pointer exception at Authentication au = super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
The au is null.